# Problem About TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.3**

`TimeLinePlot` was introduced in 10.1

---

I have some data from wikipedia.

```
str = URLFetch["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica"];
AllDate = StringCases[str, DatePattern[{"MonthName", " ", "Day", ", ","Year"}]][[;; 26]];
AllVersion = StringCases[str, "<li>Mathematica " ~~ Shortest[v__] ~~ "(" :> v][[-26 ;;]];
```

Now I can show some interesting,like this:

```
ShowDifferenceDate[version_, 
   date_] := {Rule @@@ Partition[version, 2, 1], 
      DateDifference[##, {"Year"}] & @@@ Partition[date, 2, 1]} // 
      Transpose // Flatten // Partition[#, 4, 4, 1, " "] & // TableForm;
{someVersion, someDate} = Transpose[GatherBy[Transpose[{AllVersion, AllDate}], 
      StringTake[First@#, 1 ;; 2] &][[All, 1]]];
ShowDifferenceDate[AllVersion, AllDate]
ShowDifferenceDate[someVersion, someDate]
```

> picture 1 
>   [image]
>
> picture 2
>   [image]

Now I want to use TimelinePlot.It is Ok like this:

```
TimelinePlot[Association[Rule @@@ Transpose@{AllVersion, DateList /@ AllDate}]]
```

> picture 3
>   [image]

It is ugly.So I want to make it beautiful.For example,different colors for different Big Version(1.0,1.1,1.2 are the same color, but 1.0,2.0 are different color).So I try to do this:

```
TimelinePlot[Association /@ 
  GatherBy[Rule@@@Transpose@{AllVersion,DateList/@AllDate}, StringTake[First@#, 1 ;; 2] &]]
```

But it Failed.

> Part::partw : 
>     Part2 of {{Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], 
>         RGBColor[0.368, 0.507, 0.710],AbsoluteThickness[1.6`], Opacity[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK6FE.png)]}} does not exist.

Why it Failed? Is it bug about TimelinePlot?

How to make this picture(TimelinePlot) beautiful?

Thanks!

Comment: @Mahdi Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: You're welcome. I had a typo in my own comment, so funny! :D

Comment: @Mahdi Did you post the answer as a comment and then delete it? I'm trying to figure out whether this question can be closed or not, and it's complicated if I don't know for sure that it's been answered or whether the mistake was "simple" (requirement for closing the question.)

Comment: @Pickett Sorry.My code is missing a comma at the beginning due to my carelessness,so Mahdi told me this mistake,and then I add one comma in my code.But my problem is not settled.

Comment: It appears that TimeLinePlot doesn't work correctly with lists of associations.

Comment: The other work around that the help on TimelinePlot suggests to me is to use a customised Labeled function where the Label format is different for Major and  Minor versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug appears to be fixed in MMA 10.3:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One can workaround this issue by using nested lists instead of associations.

```
TimelinePlot[GatherBy[
  Rule @@@ Transpose@{DateList /@ AllDate, AllVersion}, 
  StringTake[Last@#, 1 ;; 2] &
]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It appears that TimelinePlot doesn't handle multiple Associations very gracefully.  One imperfect workaround is to use `Show`

```
tlp1 = TimelinePlot[{Entity["HistoricalEvent", "WorldWar2"], 
Entity["HistoricalEvent", "VietnamWar"]}];

tlp2 = TimelinePlot[{Style[{Entity["HistoricalEvent", "WorldWar1"], 
  Entity["HistoricalEvent", "KoreanWarBegins"]}, Red]}];

Show[tlp1, tlp2]
```

Gives :

[image]

You can probably tweak it but you get the gist.

Comment: Multiple associations *should* work however, right?  So I think this is a bug; do you?

Comment: @mr.wizard. I agree.  Tried it with Datasets too with similar errors.